WooCommerce Attributes' Filter Relationship
In WooCommerce, there is an attributes' filter that, by default, does not change other attributes when one attribute is filtered. However, I wanted to establish a relationship between all attribute filters.
For example, suppose products have attributes like country, brand, and capacity. When a user selects 'France' for the country attribute, only products with the country set to 'France' should be displayed on the product list page. Additionally, the brand and capacity filters should update to show only the options available for products from 'France'.
Regards,

I was able to achieve this using the woocommerce_product_query action and the $query->set('tax_query', ...) function. Here is the solution:
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_filter_woocommerce_products', 10, 2);
function custom_filter_woocommerce_products($query)
{
    // Check if we are on a product archive page
    if (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag()) {

        // Get selected attributes from URL
        $selected_attributes = [];
        // Get all registered attribute taxonomies
        $attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();

        // Loop through each attribute taxonomy to check if it's set in the URL
        foreach ($attribute_taxonomies as $attribute) {
            $taxonomy = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($attribute->attribute_name);
            $taxonomy = str_replace('pa_', 'filter_', $taxonomy);

            // Check if this taxonomy is set in the URL
            if (isset($_GET[$taxonomy])) {
                $terms = explode(',', $_GET[$taxonomy]);
                $selected_attributes[$taxonomy] = array_map('sanitize_text_field', $terms);
            }
        }

        if (!empty($selected_attributes)) {
            $tax_query = [];

            // Loop through selected attributes and build tax query
            foreach ($selected_attributes as $taxonomy => $terms) {
                $taxonomy = str_replace('filter_', 'pa_', $taxonomy);
                $tax_query[] = [
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $terms,
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ];
            }

            // Apply the tax queries to main query
            if (!empty($tax_query)) {
                $tax_query['relation'] = 'AND';
                $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
            }
        }
    }
}

I hope this solution is helpful for those looking to create interdependent attribute filters in WooCommerce.
